# Azure single sign on 502 bad gateway

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, single-sign-on, http-status-code-502

We are facing 502 bad gateway error on web portal which uses our client Azure App registration settings.

Client provided us the following details with single username / password form their domanin to test SSO

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "XXXXX.co.uk",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/SignInVerify",
    "SignOutPath": "/aad-signout"
  }
```

We deployed website, tested everything using the user provided and all seems to be working for user client provided.

When more user tried to use this website, they get 502 bad gateway erorr but we can still use username/password provided to us without any issue.

Client is large corporate client could have multiple Azure tenant for Azure Active Directory and we don't know their user group structure etc.

What could be the cause of the issue for all user other than the one we can currnetly test/use?

Thank you for your help in advance on this.

Comment: Please refer [Troubleshooting bad gateway errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502#overview)

Comment: This error could indicate a misconfiguration of the application.

Comment: A bad gateway error indicates that the connector is unable to reach the backend application. Make sure that you have published the correct application..Check if you have a typo or mistake in the internal URL OR Not publishing the root of the application.

Comment: Add server.listener.keepAliveTimeout = 120e3; The keepAliveTimeout on your http service (apache,node/express/hapi, nginx) will kill the connection if the client (gateway) does not complete the request within 5 seconds.

Comment: Hi - in my case it's working for one user but not for other user... do you know what could be cause of this? Thank you

Comment: Please refer [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/164578/502-bad-gateway.html) for 502 Bad Gateway

Answer (score 0):

Change the configuration to below format :

```cs
{  
"AzureAd": {  
"Instance": "[https://login.microsoftonline.com/"](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%22 "https://login.microsoftonline.com/%22"),  
"Domain": "microsoft.onmicrosoft.com",  
"TenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",  
"ClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",  
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",  
"SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-callback-oidc"  
},
```

And also check that you have selected multitenant

[image]

Comment: It looks like you've unintentionally added Markdown formatting into your code block for the "Instance" attribute.